# Cómo hacer sum de un atributo de la clase de la lista utilizando linq?

Tags: c#, linq

¿Como hago un `linq` del siguiente escenario?

Tengo una clase Producto que tiene un atributo precio, y tengo un `List<Producto>`, quiero hacer un `sum` al atributo precio de todos los objetos que tiene la lista:

Algo así como:

```
suma = sum(Lista.precio);
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 6):

Para sumar haciendo uso de `LINQ` y expresiones `lambda`, realiza lo siguiente:

```
double suma = miLista.Sum(item => item.precio);
```